# chroot into a sshfs folder

Tags: files, permissions, chroot, sshfs, fuse

I am trying to chroot into a sshfs-mounted directory:

```
mkdir remoteroot
sshfs remote:/ remoteroot/
sudo chroot remoteroot/
```

but I get `chroot: cannot change root directory to remoteroot/: Permission denied`. Am I doing something wrong or is this simply not supported? If so, are there alternatives?

Comment: Is `remoteroot/` owned by `root`?

Comment: `remoteroot/` here isn't. I found that I need `-o allow_other`, but now I'm getting `bash: /dev/null: Permission denied`, and people seem to suggest `-o dev` but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Is `bash` in your chroot?  If it is, check it's in the standard path, or add it to the `chroot` command's argument: `sudo chroot remoteroot/ /path/to/bash`

Answer (score 3):

I found that the problem is sshfs trying to prevent other users (even root) from accessing my remote filesystem. Furthemore, accessing character devices (such as `/dev/null`) is problematic, and probably not what you want, because I guess that for example piping to `/dev/null` would effectively send bytes over the network.

This is what I use now:

```
mkdir remoteroot
sshfs remote:/ remoteroot -o allow_other -o kernel_cache   #you need to enable user_allow_other in /etc/fuse.conf
sudo mount --bind /tmp/ remoteroot/tmp/
sudo mount --bind /dev remoteroot/dev
sudo mount --bind /sys remoteroot/sys
sudo mount --bind /run remoteroot/run
sudo mount --bind /var/tmp remoteroot/var/tmp
sudo chroot remoteroot
```

Consider that there might be file ownership problems, because if you `su` to another user, the remote end won't switch to the new user.

Comment: All devices will be interpreted on your local machine with their usual behaviour - you don't want to use remote `/dev` anyway, but nothing extra would go over the network.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work here. The bind mounts seem not to be created over the SSHFS file system, and when chrooting into the remote dir, I get lots of `bash: /dev/null: Permission denied`